# Create Powershell for clicking 2 button in a iFrame

Tags: javascript, powershell, sharepoint, iframe

I have an issue with my sharepoint. 
I want to map my sharepoint document library as a network drive.
There are some certification problems, so I need to connect it like this:

```
Open the IE with the correct hyperlink -> then clicking on the button "Bibliothek and after that on the button "Mit explorer öffnen"
```

HTML Code "Bibliothek":

```
> <LI title=Bibliothek class="ms-cui-tt  ms-cui-tt-s ms-cui-ct-last"
> id=Ribbon.Library-title role=tab aria-selected=true
> unselectable="on"><SPAN class=ms-cui-tt-span
> unselectable="on">Bibliothek</SPAN><A title=Bibliothek
> class=ms-cui-tt-a onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;"
> unselectable="on"></A></LI> <SPAN class=ms-cui-tt-span
> unselectable="on">Bibliothek</SPAN> <A title=Bibliothek
> class=ms-cui-tt-a onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;"
> unselectable="on"></A>
```

HTML Code "Mit explorer öffnen":

```
>     <SPAN class=ms-cui-row id=Ribbon.Library.Actions-LargeMedium-1-2 unselectable="on"><A class="ms-cui-ctl-medium "
> id=Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer-Medium role=button
> aria-describedby=Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer_ToolTip
> onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on"
> mscui:controltype="Button"><SPAN class=ms-cui-ctl-iconContainer
> unselectable="on"><SPAN class=" ms-cui-img-16by16
> ms-cui-img-cont-float" unselectable="on"><IMG style="LEFT: -176px;
> TOP: -112px" alt="" src="/_layouts/1031/images/formatmap16x16.png"
> unselectable="on"></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN class=ms-cui-ctl-mediumlabel
> unselectable="on">Mit Explorer öffnen</SPAN></A></SPAN>
```

I'm bad at javascript so I can't figure out, how to approach the two button.

Here is my latest powershell code:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.navigate('mylink')

$ie.Quit()

$Drive = "Z:"

$DrvDest = "mylinkname"

$net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network;
$net.mapnetworkdrive($Drive,$DrvDest)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

kind regards,

Antonio

Comment: Why don't you just map the SharePoint document library as a network share in PowerShell? `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive($Drive,$Library,$false,$($Credentials.username),$($Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password))`

Comment: Hello DarkLite1, thanks for your quick response. I have to change my password at least once a month. Is this a problem?

Comment: something like that ? `($ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("a") |?{$_.id -eq "Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer-Medium"}).click()`

Comment: Usually a service account with a fixed password is used to accomplish tasks like this.

Comment: thats unfortunately not possible. I think the only way in my case is to do it the powershell, because of the certification problems